# SKSpriteNode not scalling properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm developing a small game using Swift & SpriteKit. When I add a `SKSpriteNode` for Restart button, it doesn't scale properly.

The size of Restart button is 100px in height and width. If I don't set scale , it covers the whole screen and make the screen appear white. I figured out that if I `setScale` to 0.005 only than it appears on screen, but not in proper size.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class EndScene: SKScene {

    var restartBtn = SKSpriteNode()


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        background()
        restartGame()

    }


    func restartGame() {

        restartBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restartBtn")
        restartBtn.setScale(0.005)
        restartBtn.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 4)
        restartBtn.zPosition = 1

        self.addChild(restartBtn)
    }


    func background() {

        let bkg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
        bkg.size = self.frame.size
        bkg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        bkg.zPosition = -2

        self.addChild(bkg)
    }

}
```

Here is the output of this code,
[Restart Button Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo8wG.png)

**UPDATE**

I put `scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill` right inside `didMoveToView` function and it helped in rendering the shape of the SpriteNode properly. But still I have to `setScale(0.001)` to make the size of Restart button fit in the screen. Can anyone assist me what line of code I'm still missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .setScale try using restartBtn.size = CGSize(Width: 50, Height: 50)

This uses the Sprite Kit's resize formula.

Comment: I have already tried that as well but it doesn't give any different result. To use CGSize I have to put width and height '0.1' to make it visible on screen, and it still renders in oval shape instead of being round.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. It happened when I forgot to specify the size of the scene. Instead of calling `initWithSize` I just wrote `init` and the scene started to scale down all nodes by x1000. Nodes were visible, but they required a scale of 0.001